# Why is class X is not assignable to new(...)=> X error occurring: "Type 'X' is not assignable to type 'new (...args) => X'"?

Tags: typescript, generics

I am trying to write a graph library in typescript for my application and I try to make it as generic as possible. However, I encounter this problem of type unrecognition in my code and I am not sure why it is happening. In short, BasicVertex is a concrete child class of the abstract class GraphVertex; BasicEdge is a concrete child class of the abstract class GraphEdge. CoupleGraph implements interface IGraph.

In my plan, CoupleGraph requires a concrete child class of GraphVertex (something that extends GraphVertex and instantiable) and a concrete child class of GraphEdge (something that extends GraphEdge and instantiable). Here is my code:

```
export abstract class GraphVertex<KT, VT> {
    public abstract getKey(): KT;
    public abstract getValue():VT;
}

export abstract class GraphEdge<KT, VT, EKT, EVT>{
    edgeDirectional: boolean = false;
    edgeWeighted: boolean = false;
    // node1: GraphNode<KT, VT>;
    // node2: GraphNode<KT, VT>;
    weight?: number;

    abstract getKey(): EKT;

    abstract getNodeKeyLeadTo(nodeKey:KT):KT;
}


export interface IGraph<KT, VT, EKT, EVT> {
    getNodes(): GraphVertex<KT, VT>[];

    getNodeKeys(): KT[];

    getNeighborVertices(node: KT): GraphVertex<KT,VT>[];
    getNeighborVerticeKeys(node: KT): KT[];

    getEdges(): GraphEdge<KT,VT, EKT, EVT>[];

    getIncidentEdges(node:KT): GraphEdge<KT,VT, EKT, EVT>[];

    getIncidentEdgeKeys(node:KT): EKT[];

    areAdjacent(node1: KT, node2: KT): boolean;

    insertNode(key:KT, value:VT):void;

    removeNode(key:KT):void;

    insertEdge(key1:KT, key2:KT, weight?:number): void;

    removeEdge(key1:KT, key2: KT):void;

    getNodeByKey(nodeKey:KT):GraphVertex<KT,VT>;

    getEdgeByKey(edgeKey:EKT):GraphEdge<KT,VT,EKT,EVT>;
}

export type InitableKeyValueVertexClass<KT,VT> = GraphVertex<KT,VT> & (new(key:KT, value:VT)=>GraphVertex<KT,VT>);
export type InitableValueDefinedEdgeClass<VKT,VVT,EKT,EVT> = GraphEdge<VKT,VVT,EKT,EVT> & (new(fromNodeKey:VKT,toNodeKey:VKT,value:EVT)=>InitableValueDefinedEdgeClass<VKT,VVT,EKT,EVT>);

export class CoupleGraph<VKT,VVT,EKT,EVT,VertexClass extends InitableKeyValueVertexClass<VKT,VVT>,EdgeClass extends InitableValueDefinedEdgeClass<VKT,VVT,EKT,EVT>> implements IGraph<VKT,VVT,EKT,EVT> {
    
    nodesMap:Map<VKT, VertexClass>;
    edgesMap:Map<EKT, EdgeClass>;
    nodeEdgesMap:Map<VKT,EKT[]>;
    VertexObject:new(key:VKT, value:VVT)=> VertexClass;
    EdgeObject:new(fromNodeKey:VKT,toNodeKey:VKT,value:EVT)=>EdgeClass

    constructor(VertexObject:new(key:VKT, value:VVT)=> VertexClass, EdgeObject:new(fromNodeKey:VKT,toNodeKey:VKT,value:EVT)=>EdgeClass) {
        // super();
        this.nodesMap = new Map<VKT,VertexClass>();
        this.edgesMap = new Map<EKT,EdgeClass>();
        this.nodeEdgesMap = new Map<VKT,EKT[]>();
        this.VertexObject = VertexObject;
        this.EdgeObject = EdgeObject;
    }

    public getNodes(): VertexClass[] {
        const nodes:VertexClass[] = [];
        for (const [nodeKey, node] of this.nodesMap) {
            nodes.push(node);
        }
        return nodes;
    }

    public getNodeKeys(): VKT[] {
        const nodes:VKT[] = [];
        for (const [nodeKey, node] of this.nodesMap) {
            nodes.push(nodeKey);
        }
        return nodes;
    }

    public getNeighborVertices(nodeKey: VKT): VertexClass[] {
        const nodes:VertexClass[] = [];
        const edgeKeys =  this.getIncidentEdgeKeys(nodeKey);
        for (const edgeKey of edgeKeys) {
            const edge = this.getEdgeByKey(edgeKey);
            const otherNodeKey = edge.getNodeKeyLeadTo(nodeKey);
            nodes.push(this.getNodeByKey(otherNodeKey));
        }
        return nodes;
    }

    public getNodeByKey(nodeKey:VKT) {
        const node = this.nodesMap.get(nodeKey);

        if (!node) throw new Error(`Node with key [${nodeKey}] not exist`);

        return node;
    }

    public getEdgeByKey(edgeKey:EKT) {
        const edge = this.edgesMap.get(edgeKey);
        if (!edge) throw new Error(`Edge with key ${edgeKey} not exist`);
        return edge;
    }

    public getNeighborVerticeKeys(nodeKey: VKT): VKT[] {
        const nodeKeys:VKT[] = [];
        const edgeKeys =  this.getIncidentEdgeKeys(nodeKey);
        for (const edgeKey of edgeKeys) {
            const edge = this.getEdgeByKey(edgeKey);
            const otherNodeKey = edge.getNodeKeyLeadTo(nodeKey);
            nodeKeys.push(otherNodeKey);
        }
        return nodeKeys;
    }
    public getEdges(): EdgeClass[] {
        const edges:EdgeClass[] = [];
        for (const [edgeKey, edge] of this.edgesMap) {
            edges.push(edge);
        }
        return edges;
    }
    public getIncidentEdges(nodeKey: VKT): EdgeClass[] {
        const edges:EdgeClass[] = [];
        for (const edgeKey of this.getIncidentEdgeKeys(nodeKey)) {
            edges.push(this.getEdgeByKey(edgeKey));
        }
        return edges;
    }
    public getIncidentEdgeKeys(node: VKT): EKT[] {
        const edgeKeys =  this.nodeEdgesMap.get(node);
        if (!edgeKeys) throw new Error(`Node with key ${node} not exist`);
        return edgeKeys;
    }
    public areAdjacent(node1: VKT, node2: VKT): boolean {
        const edges = this.getIncidentEdges(node1);
        for (const edge of edges) {
            const otherNodeKey = edge.getNodeKeyLeadTo(node1);
            if (otherNodeKey === node2) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public insertNode(key: VKT, value: VVT): void {
        const existNode = this.nodesMap.get(key);
        if (existNode) throw new Error(`Fail to get Vertex: vertex with key ${key} already exists.`);
        
        const node = new this.VertexObject(key,value);
    }
    public removeNode(key: VKT): void {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }
    public insertEdge(key1: VKT, key2: VKT, weight?: number | undefined): void {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }
    public removeEdge(key1: VKT, key2: VKT): void {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }
    
}

class BasicVertex<VKT,VVT> extends GraphVertex<VKT,VVT> {
    
    key:VKT;
    value:VVT
    constructor(key:VKT,value:VVT) {
        super();
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    getValue(): VVT {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }
    public getKey(): VKT {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }
}

class BasicEdge<VKT,VVT,EKT,EVT> extends GraphEdge<VKT,VVT,EKT,EVT> {
    fromNodeKey:VKT;
    constructor(fromNodeKey:VKT,toNodeKey:VKT,value:EVT) {
        super();
        this.fromNodeKey = fromNodeKey;
    }
    getKey(): EKT {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }
    getNodeKeyLeadTo(nodeKey: VKT): VKT {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }
}
```

My above implementation is compilable and syntax-correct. But when I try to instantiate a **CoupleGraph** that takes **BasicVertex** and **BasicEdge**:

```
const g = new CoupleGraph<string,string,string,string,
    BasicVertex<string,string>,
    BasicEdge<string, string, string, string>>(BasicVertex, BasicEdge);
```

I got error

```
Type 'BasicVertex<string, string>' does not satisfy the constraint 'GraphVertex<string, string> & (new (key: string, value: string) => GraphVertex<string, string>)'.
  Type 'BasicVertex<string, string>' is not assignable to type 'new (key: string, value: string) => 
GraphVertex<string, string>'.
    Type 'BasicVertex<string, string>' provides no match for the signature 'new (key: string, value: string): GraphVertex<string, string>'.
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error cuz BasicVertex<string, string> has constructor (key:string,value:string)=>BasicVertex<string,string> which should satisfy the signature.

And the following code also has no error in syntax or in compiling.

```
const v: new(key:string, value:string)=>GraphVertex<string,string>&GraphVertex<string,string> = BasicVertex<string,string>;
```

which means BasicVertex satisfies the type constraint right? So why is the error occurring?

Comment: Please consider removing as much code from your example as you can while still reproducing the issue.  That's the "minimal" part of a [mre].

Comment: Your final line `const v: new(key:string, value:string)=>GraphVertex<string,string>&GraphVertex<string,string> = ...` likely doesn't mean what you think it means; parentheses will help you be explicit.  You seem to mean `const v: (new(key:string, value:string)=>GraphVertex<string,string>)&GraphVertex<string,string>` but the compiler interprets it as `const v: new(key:string, value:string)=>(GraphVertex<string,string>&GraphVertex<string,string>)`.  Please consider using parentheses and [edit]ing if your assumptions are wrong.

Comment: Can you explain what you intend `GraphVertex<KT,VT> & (new(key:KT, value:VT)=>GraphVertex<KT,VT>);` to be?  On the face of it that is the type of an instance of `GraphVertex` which is also a *constructor* of `GraphVertex`.  It's very rare for an object in JavaScript to be both an instance and a constructor of the same type, so it's unlikely to be what you want.  The actual use case probably calls for *either* an instance *or* a constructor, but it's not clear to me which you want.  Hopefully you'll pare this down to a [mre] from which it will be more obvious.